# What does this serverless functions log on Netlify mean?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, serverless, netlify

I know this is a stupid question from a beginner. However, I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding what this "SSR Handler" log in the "Functions" tab means.

I recently created a website using NextJS 14. It is using App Router and all pages are "Server Side Components", with only a few Client Side components. This is all a little new to me. I received an email from Netlify saying that I have already reached 50% usage of "Invocations", and when I look at this log, it keeps showing new records every second, as if there were dozens of people using my website. However, the website has just been launched and has not been advertised. In fact, Google Analytics shows that no one is using it. So, what does this log mean and why doesn't it stop recording invocations every few seconds? It's about to max out my plan and I don't know how to resolve it. How can a website without access generate this situation? I pay the Netlify PRO plan.

Please be patient with me, I still understand very little about this part of development.

[The Netlify email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zUPe.png)

["SSR Handler" Function Log. The records are not just from this "video" page, but from almost all pages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iIvN.png)

[Functions panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgW4U.png)

[Requests passing 50% of the limit and increasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWwXg.png)

I deployed the same repository to Vercel, with a free domain, free plan, etc., to see what would happen. This is not happening there, only records appear in the logs when I open the site and use it. However, not at Netlify, these records continually appear in the log, second by second, even though I don't open the site and Analytics says that no one is using it. I believe this rules out the option of it being a loop or error in the code, but something related to Netlify perhaps?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have all or too many of your functions defined as using SSR rather than ISR;  ISR will run once per revalidation period  that you specify and then be cached for the rest of that period, or cached until you redeploy in the same context - the latter only if you specified a revalidation window longer than the time between your deploys or failed to specify a timeout at all.  (One presumes that your production context is the one that is receiving so much traffic, but if you did something unexpected like set a load testing script up against staging, that could trigger it as well, hence me mentioning contexts at all:  https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/overview/#deploy-contexts)

To fix, I'd recommend two things:

1. checking current config, and then changing your functions to ISR unless they really need to run on every visit, to avoid running out of what is provided for free with the Pro plan.  If you overrun what is free, you will be liable for additional function package charges, and most folks don't truly need most or many of their routes to be SSR and thus be run so frequently.
2. You might also have a buggy or overcomplicated spec in next.config.js on what needs "middleware" run, which can also lead to unexpected function runs even on static files.  This doc may help you understand how to configure this differently:  https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/next-js/middleware/

Note that as a Pro customer, Netlify's tech support team will respond to an email from you and can see more about your usage than we can from here, in case you need help changing one of the above in your specific codebase.

Comment: I definitely have a lot to learn yet. Thank you for the answer, I will study the subject of ISR further and try to optimize the project with this. Fortunately, the problem reported in the question was "resolved" after I removed the domain from Netlify, deployed the same project to Vercel and added the domain there. I simply don't know the reason, but now the requests are happening normally, only with visits from bots or real users. I still don't understand what was happening at Netlify. At least the problem wasn't in the code apparently.